# Vanilla JS: HTML Elements are being fetched after executing all JS work in click event listener

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I have a button
`<input id="next-btn" class='button' type='button' value='Next'>`

and a click event listener

```
const nextBtn = document.getElementById('next-btn');
nextBtn.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
  const nextBtn: any = document.getElementById('next-btn');
  nextBtn.style.backgroundColor = '#84e757';
  nextBtn.value = 'Wait...';
  
  // Some complex JS Work that takes like 2 seconds
});
```

I want to change the button from `Next` into `Wait...` when the user clicks on the button.

What is actually happen is that the button HTML element is not being fetched until all the JS logic finishes.

That's stopping me from adding a loader. How to solve this issue please?

**Note:** This is being implemented in an electron JS app

Answer (score 0):

**My friend here is the solution to update the UI to the HTML element with JavaScript event listener**

```
let nextBtn = document.querySelector("#next-btn");

nextBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  nextBtn.style.backgroundColor = "#84E757";
  nextBtn.value = "Wait...";
});
```